# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined how can i remove the dependency of the code in rawMarkUp?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

just registered here.

Was following a tutorial and I encountered this error when I compile it. Hope someone can help me see the cause of the error :)

Thanks so much.

`enter code here`[Codepen  Dump](https://codepen.io/noeru_Ethernalz/pen/KRqqBm)

Comment: Please remove the comments and add your code + error to the actual question instead of the title.

Answer (score 0):

`CommentList` should be accessing the `data` prop with `this.props.data` instead of `this.state.data`.

You also tried to access the `comments` property of `data`, which is an array in `CommentBox`:

```
<CommentList data={this.state.data.comments} />
```

If you are just concatenating the comments to `this.state.data`, then you can just use `<CommentList data={this.state.data} />`.

Comment: Thanks riwu, updated the codepen dump as you suggested, still the same error :( Thanks

Comment: I still see `this.state.data.comments`.

Comment: Updated the codepen, but when I do compile it on my desktop I now get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null, Just noticed react version being used on codepen is 15, while I'm using on my desktop is 16

Comment: Which line is it and can you log the value that `map` is called on? And what did you do on the codepen to trigger that error? You can try creating an example on https://codesandbox.io/s/new instead.

Comment: Hi riwu, replicated it on sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/q7yox2zz34

but i'm getting a different error there its not reading the marked.js in relation to the 'map' error its on line 56 of the codepen link

Comment: Make sure you save the changes on every file before sharing the link. This compiles for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/21jjvl41yp. I commented out the `__loadComments` code because you didn't include the `database` prop.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error usually means you are trying to read your data before it becomes available ? Try and add a check for your data before you read them. Example your CommentList class below

```
class CommentList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const CommentNodes = this.props.data.map((comment)=>{
            return (
                <Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.id}>{comment.txt}
                </Comment>
            );
        });
        return (
            <div className='commentList'>
                <h2>Comments:</h2>
                {CommentNodes}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

add a checking on commentNode like ,

```
const CommentNodes = this.props.data ? this.props.data.map((comment)=>{
                return (
                    <Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.id}>{comment.txt}
                    </Comment>
                );
            });
        : null;
```

or better

```
class CommentList extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div className='commentList'>
                    <h2>Comments:</h2>
                    {this.props.data && 
                      this.props.data.map((comment)=>{
                        return(
                         <Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.id}> 
                          {comment.txt}
                         </Comment>
                       )
                     }
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

This way you can avoid such type of error above. Read through your code and apply similar checking wherever you access or read a data or pros that might be empty at some case.

**Update**

Regarding the export issue. If your classes are in the same js file and doesn't need to use it in another file, then you dont need to export them . just

```
class CommentBox extends React.Component {

}
```

as example. However, if you need lets say `CommentBox` and `Comment` in another files and they are in separate files, Then you need to export them like below.

commentBoxComponent.ts

```
export default class CommentBox extends React.Component {
  ....
}
```

and 
comment.ts

```
export default class Comment extends React.Component {
  ....
}
```

And you import them in your desired file like,

```
import CommentComponet from './path/CommentComponent.ts';
import CommentBox from './path/CommentBox.ts';l
```

However, if they are both in the same file(i.e both Comment and CommentBox). Then you can export them as variables not default like below

components.ts

```
export class Comment extends React.Component {
  ....
}

export class CommentBox extends React.Component {
  ....
}
```

And to import

```
import {CommentBox, Comment} from './path/component.ts';
```

Comment: Hi Nuru, did what you suggested for the class CommentList 

now I encounter Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined (Inside Comment Class)

is there a way I can just remove the mark /rawMarkup function as I guess the mark.js is not being read

Comment: got your suggestion but still got the same error mentioned on my previous comment. Thanks

Comment: @Nerou your error means `this.props.children` in Comment class is undefined which by extension means `comment.txt` from CommentList class is undefined. Can you pls confirm whether thats the case or not ?

Comment: yup that's the case, I somehow fixed it and now whenever I press post button I get this  this.props.onCommentSubmit is not a function but im sure it is declared properly unless I missed stuff

Comment: export default (CommentForm, CommentList, CommentBox, Comment) When I do this, I get the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

but when I exclude the comment from export, I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'child' of undefined

if I remove the CommetBox, I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

if only CommentForm is exported, it works but if I press post, I get the onCommentSubmit is not a function T_T

Comment: Thanks so much this helped me